# Github SSH works but clone using ssh fails

Tags: git, github, ssh, git-config

I came across a weird issue while cloning a git repository using ssh. I have the ssh setup:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
Hi yusufali2205! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

I am using the right clone url and have access to the repo I want to clone. But getting error:

```
➤ git clone git@github.com:<some-org>/<repo>.git
Cloning into 'project'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

There is no other message to debug what is wrong with my ssh setup or git configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out there was an entry in my `.gitconfig` which was replacing ssh with https.

```
[url "https"]
    insteadOf = git
```

I might have accidentally added this entry while using some tool. So the clone command was actually using the url `https@github.com:<some-org>/<repo>.git`

After removing the above entry from `.gitconfig` the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same issue, but in my case it was because I named my key files using a custom name (e.g., `my_key` and `my_key.pub`), and not letting `ssh-keygen` use the default ones, which are:

- id_rsa
- id_dsa
- id_ecdsa
- id_ed25519
- id_ed25519_sk
- id_xmss

If you add the custom named key using `ssh-add` (as many tutorials say to do), then the command `ssh -T git@github.com` works perfectly, but not the `git clone` command.
This is due to the fact that `git` looks only for keys with default names when using ssh.

I was able to determine this by adding to the global `.gitconfig` the following property:

```
[core]
    sshCommand = ssh -vvv
```

which basically spits out all the log messages when you try to clone a repository (or other git operations) when using ssh.

**Note**: I'm on Windows 10, and it could be that the issue is also related on how to `git` works on Windows. I have not tested this on *nix systems.

Comment: Thanks for the core.sshCommand in .gitconfig. Very helpful! `git config --global core.sshCommand "ssh -vvv"`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had to delete ~/.ssh/known_hosts file, so that while cloning, it will remake that file. After this, it worked

Comment: My case was slightly different to OP. After an upgrade of our GitHub server the ssh clone worked fine but the https clone would hang and give 404, eventually. I think the issue is under the hood somewhere the ssh connection was waiting for the user to accept the new id of the server. I didn't delete the whole file I just removed the single entry for our GH server from the known_hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and researching I tried something and I got it. Go to your .ssh directory, open the file known_hosts with the notepad, right at the beginning it has "github.com" ... insert SSH: at the beginning of github.com and it will look like this: "SSH: github.com" and save, try again. It worked for me!