# ssh agent on windows keep forgetting ssh key

Tags: windows, ssh, ssh-agent

Have a ssh-key here c:/Users/User1/.ssh/github_rsa.
I added it to ssh-agent using commands

```
eval $(ssh-agent -s)
ssh-add ~/.ssh/githab_rsa
```

After rebooting PC ssh agent does not see my ssh key. I have to add it once more using commands

```
 eval $(ssh-agent -s)
 ssh-add ~/.ssh/githab_rsa
```

How to urge ssh-agent to remember my ssh key on PC.

Comment: Did you try to add your command/script to your startup folder ?

Comment: hmm. is not it too complicated? i was hoping to change some "config" file to make it remember my keys.

Comment: Ssh-agent is not a service so when you restart, it stops and do not restart automatically...

Comment: so what can i do to fix it all

Comment: Do you have a pass phrase for your ssh key ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty old question, but it can be useful for someone else.
A few thing to check:

1. Run `where ssh`. This command will show the available ssh versions. If there are more than one version they can conflict with each other. Try to set the default ssh version as it is described here: https://www.fmendo.com/blog/configure-git-windows-openssh/
2. Try to run `ssh -T git@github.com`. This will show whether you able to connect to your GitHub account or not. If this command returns massage like *You've successfully authenticated* it is a good sign, see 3rd point.
3. Check if your private and public keys have default names. Sometimes Git has issues with keys that have custom names. If this is the case, try to use default names https://stackoverflow.com/a/70866215/5868267